# Dynamically added Radio button does not work properly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I'm trying to add a Radio button to an existing Radio Group, but the dynamically added one does not work properly, meaning it does not "uncheck" the other ones in the group.

Note: when I click the ones that are pre-created in the XML file, it only "unchecks" the pre-created ones and not the dynamic one.

```
RadioGroup rgQ = (RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.rgQ);
RadioButton[] rbQ = new RadioButton[4];
for(int i = 1; i<5; i++) {
    rbQ[i-1] = new RadioButton(this); 
    rbQ[i-1].setText(""+i);
    rgQ.addView(rbQ[i-1]);
}
```

Comment: Why the `i-1`? Wouldn't it be better to just start `i` at `0`?

Comment: Instead of adding dynamiccally, you can use View.setVisibility(int)? to add and remove them from the group

Comment: @JesseJ: hi, i'm just testing with it, I could revert it to i=0 later.

Comment: @user1281750: hi, I've just tested the .setVisibiilty method... it messed up the form (there is empty space in the place of that hidden radiobutton)

Comment: Have you used View.GONE? (Do not use View.INVISIBLE) what layout is the radiogroup embedded in?

Comment: are you trying to add to a radio group that already has predefined radio buttons? If so try to add the radio buttons to an empty radio group to see what happens. Or perhaps you should set the onCheckChangedListener. I did something like this before it worked fine, but I do not have the code on hand now

Comment: @user1281750: View.GONE works great ! I'll use this method until I can somehow solve the original problem. Thanks a lot !
Almost forgot, I set the radiogroup in a table row of a TableLayout

Comment: @Ray: Hi, I've tried both predefined and dynamic radiogroup like you mentioned, but both still have that problem. I don't know about onCheckChangedListener though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding radiobuttons to the radiogroup dynamically. you can predefine all radiobuttons in xml and use the visibility of the view object to hide/show them.

HIDE:

```
 radioButton1.setVisibilty(View.GONE);
```

SHOW:

```
 radioButton1.setVisibilty(View.VISIBLE);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Yep ! It works ! Still not the way I want but it's good for now. Thanks !

Comment: Can you accept the answer? also a note about  Ray comment is that a CheckOnChangeListener can help managing which items are checked and which aren't

Comment: How do I do that ?
Edit: nvm, I found the button.